# How to make textAlignment under TextView visible in Android Studio 3.1.2 in the attributes?

Tags: android, android-studio, attributes, text-alignment, design-view

I'm following an online tutorial about Android Studio. But in the video clip, the instructor use textAlignment which is under textAppearance which is under textView under Attributes. In Design View. I looked on the developer website but couldn't find the answer. In my Android Studio 3.1.2, it stops with textStyle (B,I,Tt). I would like to add this function to my attributes.

Screenshot from instructor video

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You can not, there is no option for it but you can handle this by using "View All Attributes" -> "gravity". Click the text and then click the "View All Attributes" at the bottom of the options sidebar.

[image: View All Attributes]

Then look for "gravity" or search. Then pick the options you want.

[image: gravity]

Comment: Thanks. Please is there a way to move the 'gravity' attribute into list of favorites attribute for faster reach ?

Comment: You are welcome Israel. Actually, i have no idea about attribute shortcuts. I made a search on google but i could not find anything useful.

Comment: Oh, i figured it out eventually. If you hover on each attribute, there is a star icon that shows up at the left side, click on the star icon and it will be added to list of fewer attributes in the 'favorite' section

Answer (score 0):

You should use your Text tab instead of the Design one; it's better to learn XML through code than visual design.

You can still use the attribute textAlignment in your Text.

Just do this, select Text to go to the code editor.

[image]

and then just add the attribute to your textview.

[image]

You can select any alignment you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any attribute your 'favorite' which will make them visible in the fewer attributes section

[image]